# DataTables get data from render row parameter

Tags: javascript, function, object, datatables, render

I'm using DataTables pluging for Jquery, this is what I'm trying to do:

```
$('#familiars').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: "/familiars/list/",
    columns: [
        { data: 'id' },
        { data: 'name' },
        { data: 'lastname' },
        { data: 'age' },
        { data: 'country'  },
        { data: 'address' },
        { data: 'id', render : function (data, type, row){                
            btn='<a class="btn btn-success" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-edit" onclick="setRow( \'' +row+ '\' )"/><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</a>';               
        return btn;
            }
        },
    ],
});

function setRow(row){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
    console.log(row);
    console.log(row.id);
    console.log(row.name);
}
```

Pass the row parameter through the function to get all the data from the row and use it to a edit form modal but in the function setRow I only get **object Object** in all that's trys

If I use for example **row.name** or **data** in the **onclick="setRow( \'' +row+ '\' )"/** get the info but I want get all in the row parameter or another way to get all the row info to the function.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: from the [docs](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().data()) so you can just change the event in the doc from 'click', 'tr', function() to 'click', 'tr button', function() 

and remove the "onclick" thing in your render

Comment: Thanks! I remove the onclick event and its working like this:

$('#t_familiars tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
        var data = t_familiars.row( this ).data() ;
        alert(data['name']);
    });

Comment: :) glad to hear that! have fun coding